# How to remove rows with 0 values from an indexed series in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb, drop, indexed

I have a series indexed by date:

```
s = indexedSeries(2011.12.30..2012.01.01, [0, 60, 0])
```

I want to remove all rows with 0 values from the series. How should I script this in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = indexedSeries(2011.12.30..2012.01.01, [0, 60, 0])
```

To remove all rows with 0 values try this.

```
s = select * from s where value != 0
```

Or:

```
s = s[s != 0]
```

You can also use filter function to achieve the same result.

```
s = filter(s, s != 0)
```

Hope it helps